# How do I combine formatted page numbers in an index

Tags: formatting, indexing, page-numbering

If I format page numbers in an index, they show up in addition to non-formatted numbers. This minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx} \makeindex \begin{document} page 1    
\index{foo}        % normal page number
\index{foo|textbf} % bold page number
\index{bar}        % normal page number    
\pagebreak page 2
\index{bar|textbf} % bold page number
\printindex \end{document}
```

Creates the following index

bar, 1, **2**
foo, 1, **1**

But I would prefer to combine a normal page number and a formatted page number as bold page number and also allow formatted page number in page sequences:

bar, 1-**2**
foo, **1**

Maybe page sequences are too complicate, for instance if page 1 and 3 are normal, but page 2 is formatted. But at least the duplicated single page number (in this example "1, **1**") should not be there.

More precise I do not use `textbf` but a custom `bfhref` for hyperlinked page numbers, but this should not be the issue

```
\newcommand{\bfhref}[1]{\textbf{\hyperpage{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process from `idx` file to `ind` is controlled by the command `makeindex`. I can not find any options about your demand. An alternative way to remove those duplicated pages is to deal with `*.ind` file yourself. For example, you can replace the pattern `num, \textbf{num}` with `\textbf{num}`. It's easy to accomplish with any editor supporting regular expression replacement.

And by default only three or more successive pages will be abbreviated as a range.

e.g.

bar, 1, **2**, 3--6 .

I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thank. As there is no TeX solution, I'll hack a script to clean up the `idx` file. I use `splitindex` which itself calls `makeindex`. Maybe I do not have to manually change the `idx` file with `xindy`, which looks better than `makeindex` but has its own drawbacks (biblatex replaces bibtex for good reason, but makeindex is still most used despite its problems).