# Double index if formatting is used

Tags: indexing

I have a document with an index where some entries (the main ones) are marked in bold.

Im using makeindex.

> My Entry, 2, 4-5, **10**, 15

Now if I have the same entry twice in the page where the *main* one is present the index is printed twice.

For example if `My Entry` is in the same page twice, once normal and once formatted bold:

```
Bla bla\index{My Entry} bla bla \index{My Entry|textbf}
```

the result is

> My Entry, 10, **10**

The page is printed twice.

This does not occur if the formatting is not present

> My Entry, 10

Any hint?

**Edit**

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=Persone,title=Persone]
\begin{document}
Bla bla\index[Persone]{My Entry} bla bla
Bla bla\index[Persone]{My Entry|textbf} bla bla
\printindex[Persone]
\end{document}
```

Produces

> My Entry, 1,**1**

While

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=Persone,title=Persone]
\begin{document}
Bla bla\index[Persone]{My Entry} bla bla
Bla bla\index[Persone]{My Entry} bla bla
\printindex[Persone]
\end{document}
```

Produces

> My Entry, 1

without the double `1` as both are on the same page

Comment: Please always post minimum working example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the default MakeIndex backend that is used by `imakeidx`. The `makeindex` program actually does *detect* when this happens, but doesn't seem to do anything about it. If you look at the compilation transcript from `pdflatex` on your example `tex` file, you will see

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty))
Writing index file Persone.idx
(./testindex.aux) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2]This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2019] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file Persone.idx....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (2 comparisons).
Generating output file Persone.ind....done (5 lines written, 1 warning).
Output written in Persone.ind.
Transcript written in Persone.ilg.
 (./Persone.ind) [3] (./testindex.aux) )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/p
ublic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>

Output written on testindex.pdf (3 pages, 28492 bytes).
```

Telling your that there is a warning when making the index. And if you open up the transcript for `makeindex` you see

```
[Tue Dec 03 03:35 PM] ArchDesktop ~/tmp/toDelete $ cat Persone.ilg 
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2019] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file Persone.idx....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (2 comparisons).
Generating output file Persone.ind....
## Warning (input = Persone.idx, line = 2; output = Persone.ind, line = 3):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.
done (5 lines written, 1 warning).
Output written in Persone.ind.
Transcript written in Persone.ilg.
```

and it tells you exactly that it has been asked to print two index entries under the same page with the same key but with two different formatting. The implicit expectation is that **you** as the author should deal with it.

(Incidentally, this same question has been asked [9 years ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5857/119) and that was basically the answer given there.)

---

All hope is not lost, however. The `imakeidx` package also supports using `xindy` as the backend for building the index which has greater flexibility of configuration (see e.g. *The LaTeX Companion* for a short summary of what can be done). If you simply

```
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
```

instead, the default settings of `texindy` seems to prevent the duplication of the entry for page 1, but also defaults to showing the non-bolded entry instead of the bolded one. This is due to the merge rule specified in the `latex-loc-fmts.xdy` module, which read

```
(define-attributes (("default" "textbf" "textit" "hyperpage")))
```

If you reorder the line to read

```
(define-attributes (("textbf" "textit" "default" "hyperpage")))
```

then bold face will have higher priority than default when printing the index. On my computer the default search path for `xindy` is configured such that you should be able to just

1. find and copy the `latex-loc-fmts.xdy` file to your local directory
2. Edit it to replace the line with `(define-attributes...` to match the replacement listed above
3. Run `pdflatex` on your TeX file
4. Run `texindy Persone.idx`
5. Rerun `pdflatex`

And that should get you the output you want. If the search path is differently configured, you may have to play with setting the `XINDY_SEARCHPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Many thanks. For the people using overleaf: `XINDY_SEARCHPATH` must be set following https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_use_latexmkrc_with_Overleaf:_examples_and_techniques